# Abrir uma pasta na máquina do usuário e abrir um arquivo(csv,txt ou xls)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Como eu faço para abrir uma pasta na máquina do usuário? Preciso abrir a pasta e carregar um arquivo csv, txt ou xls. Eu uso MVC5

Seria mais ou menos isso. Um botão que carrega na pasta e depois eu dou um carregar que seria tipo um upload, acho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pelo que eu saiba, isso é impossível. O que tu pode fazer é um botão de Upload, aonde o usuário selecione o arquivo e envie o mesmo para o servidor da aplicação, que irá processar o mesmo.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Por questões de segurança é impossível, a não ser que o usuário o faça através de Upload.

Comment: E como eu faço isso? O que quero realmente e escolher um arquivo e carregá-lo em minha máquina. Seja por upload ou não. Como eu faço isso? Tem como? Fiz uma edição no post para exemplificar.

Comment: Quando se trabalha com aplicações Web, na manipulação de arquivos externo, deve-se por obrigação trabalhar com a input do tipo file `<input type="file">` e passar o arquivo primeiramente para o servidor que está rodando sua página e no servidor trabalhar com essas informações, isso é muito simples de fazer acredito que você esteja confundido conceitos. Nesse link: http://www.devmedia.com.br/asp-net-mvc-4-realizando-upload-e-download-de-arquivos/30244 tem uma boa explicação!

Comment: Maria, legal o tuto que vc me enviou. Realmente estava sim, confundindo o conceito e o português não nos ajuda muito, ehehehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está trabalhando com jQuery, você pode usar o [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

Comment: Ainda não testei tudo, mas o post do(a) Earendul até agora está correspondendo ao que quero.

Comment: Não está dando certo pelo exemplo do Earendul. Não consigo mascarar o botão Add Files... e nem fazer a barra de progresso funcionar. O bootstrap não está legal.

Comment: Você precisa usar certinho os CSSs do plugin pra aplicar os estilos.